# How to allow people to configure database information without editing code

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

What I am using:
Java EE

So, essentially I am making a web application that is free to use and open source, however I worry there will be users who are not familiar with java, I want these users to be able to configure DATABASE information without editing the code, would this be possible?

Things I want to try but don't know enough about:
 - A installation page, kind of like the one WHMCS and Xenforo have, however I am not sure how to make this stick, for instance, if the user restarts there web server would the information be reset.

Comment: Have you tried creating beans and injecting them?

Comment: @VarunMukundhan can you send me some documentation on how beans work?

Comment: What's the deliverable? A war, an ear, docker image something else?

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, its a .war @LevKuznetsov

Answer (score 0):

One way is,
You can make a way to read database details(hostname, port etc) from system environment variables. Users can set environment variables to add their DB details.

OR

You can create a docker image of your db and application and make a `docker-compose` file with details. then you can ask users to edit username/password in that file and then user will run 1 or 2 `docker` commands and application is up and ready.
Ex: fider is similar application and they provided through docker. for your reference https://getfider.com/docs/hosting-instance/

Note: this approach requires docker environment.

Comment: What I am trying to do is make my web app extremely easy to setup, something they can setup within 20 - 40 minutes with near to no knowledge on how it works, if that makes sense, would this route be a good option? I have never used docker images before.

Comment: Docker would help in that part. Second option is doing that. you can look at the link i provided. User has to install docker software and run 2 commands.

Answer (score 0):

Since your deliverable is a war you expect the consumer to know their app container. The typical way for a JEE app to configure persistence layer is using persistence.xml file located in META-INF/  folder. You can tell the user to prepend class path with their own persistence configuration. I understand it may sound difficult but a typical system admin should know what you're asking. This is what war deliverable really means.

If you want to make it easy for lay people, build a docker image with a database of your choice and package with your app connected to this database. People who will want more will need handholding anyway. Hopefully in the form of their own developers.